# Why no WidgetFactory.php in module_widget catalogue of Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.0

guys,
I am the novice of magento 2,I want to programmatically create a Widget via UpgradeData.php and no create Widget Type,but i am not find the WidgetFactory.php file,what i should do now,please tell me ,Thanks guys

Comment: I hope everyone will give me some advice, I am very anxious to need your help, thank you in advance，pleassssse